# How to access session variable which is array of object in angular js

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, session-variables, ng-options

There's a Location class like this:-

```
class Location
                {
                 String name;
                 String value;
                }
```

I have a variable in session like this in my JSP:-

```
<% EmployeeBean empBean = (EmployeeBean)session.getAttribute("INEmployeeBean");
 Location[] locationList = empBean.getLocations(); %>
```

I need to iterate this 'locationList' in angularJS and populate the value in drop down.
I am accessing locationList in ng-options like this:-

```
ng-options = "location.value for location in locationList track by location.name"
```

I need to know how to access this locationList in angularJS, I have tried to set this in ng-init and use but it takes the value as string not array of objects.

Also I have tried setting locationList in backend spring like this and tried to access this in angularJS:-

```
  ModalAndView mv = new ModalAndView('location');
  mv.addObject('locationList',locationList);
```

Please let me know possible approach to make this work.

Thanks,
Ritika

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the locationList comes in the shape of `'["London","Paris","New York"]'`, that would be an un-parsed JSON, because browser storage works based on Strings, for space efficiency.

To parse it, you can use `JSON.parse(locationList);`

I've made a [JSFiddle showing the string being parsed into a JSON](https://jsfiddle.net/0g5Lfs9q/). (Open dev tools and look for console.logs)

In case there's a problem when setting the stringified array in sessionStorage, you could use `angular.toJson()` to make sure it's a valid format.
[Docs here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson)

Comment: What is "type:- –"?

Comment: locationList is array of Location objects which have name and value as properties. And when I set locationList through                                    
   ng-init = "list ='locationList'". It sets the list as com.abc.Location@23453cs34 (in the form of object) where it should be set like                                       
     [{'nam':'abc','value':'xyz'}, {'name':'asd','value':'qwe'}]   so I can read name and value properties in ng-options. Also I tried using JSON.stringify but it doesn't recognize the stringify method.